# resetting iptables seems to make connections clear faster

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, iptables

I have `iptables` setup on 2 `servers`.

`Server#1` is public and `Server#2` only allows the `ip address` of `Server#1` to have `ACCESS`.

`Server#2` has a `mySQL` database that `Server#1` queries.

I ran a query and it took a long time to complete.

I found that after I ran `service iptables restart` on `Server#2` the query ran instant.

What could have been causing the `iptables` to take so long for allowing access?

How am I able to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Is this repeatable ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds as if the two events are unconnected to me.

You've probably run the query, then it got stored in the query cache, so when you re-run the query the results are fetched from cache rather than scanning the tables to retrieve the data.

Comment: it definitely has something to do with the iptables, I had it happen before and fixed it with the same solution. I also ran a different query to test your theory and it was instant.

Comment: Well, re-run the query again with `iptables` off, but before you run the query do `FLUSH QUERY CACHE` first.

Comment: trust me, your answer is not even close to what the problem was, the table only has 10 records in it

Comment: @user227958 - well,if you know what the problem was, please enlighten us.

Comment: @user227958 cool, please include that in your question along with other performance metrics you have, the current question leaves a lot to interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

it might be helpful if you actually listed the iptables.. I agree it's probably not related but if you have some kind of qos/traffic limiting it may be interesting to see. you can also try running an strace -f on the mysql process while you query both times to see what's going on.